# How do I restrict my input to only the English alphabet when using HTML 5 and the pattern attribute?

Tags: html, attributes

Everytime I try to validate a pattern in an `input` tag (text), so far in FireFox and Chrome, it does not work.  It does not work on any page.  Neither the restriction on the character input, nor the number of characters works.  I know I can use JavaScript.  I want to make it work with HTML 5, using the pattern attribute.  Am I doing it wrong?  Was it removed from the standard?

Example,

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

or my own,

```html
<form id="request" action="mypage.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Request Form</legend>
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first-name" id="first-name" pattern="^/[A-Za-z]{3}/$" title="Enter First Name" size="20">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have also tried,

```
pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"
pattern="[A-Z][a-z]{20}"
pattern="^[A-Za-z]{3}$"
```

and others.

Comment: Define "The English alphabet", *café* is a perfectly acceptable spelling in English but includes an accented e.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPWuUM8IQxDY60Wf2YZydgb1o8pDk9wXW8

Comment: @Quentin Just A-Z, a-z.  Does it work for you on the pages links I posted?

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Yes, it works on the links you posted, as well as when I made my own test case using one of the versions of code that you included.

Comment: @Quentin I do not understand the point of the link.

Comment: The point is that you are having a problem restricting what people can claim their name is and that doing so would block real names, so what you are attempting to do is probably a mistake in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin It's only for the questions sake here.  If I can't get a-z, then I sure can't get anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I got it.  My problem was I expected it to die before I hit submit.  I forgot you it doesn't react like JavaScript and the keyevent.